# entity framework core with mysql unknown column in field list

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a users table and a products table
and a many-to-many relationship between them in table UsersProducts.

Each user can request to get more products, And I decided I need to save the date when I gave the user the products

```
public class UserProduct
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateAssigned { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<UserProduct>()
    .HasKey(bc => new { UserId = bc.UserId, ProductId = bc.ProductId });

  modelBuilder.Entity<UserProduct>()
    .HasOne(bc => bc.User)
    .WithMany(b => b.Products)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.UserId);

  modelBuilder.Entity<UserProduct>()
    .HasOne(bc => bc.Product)
    .WithMany(c => c.Owners)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ProductId);

  base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

When I try to access (UsersProducts.Where(...)) it I get "unknown column in field list" in regards to DateAssigned column.

This is the code EF generated in the migration

```
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.AddColumn<DateTime>(
            name: "DateAssigned",
            table: "UsersProducts",
            type: "datetime(6)",
            nullable: false,
            defaultValue: new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Unspecified));
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
            name: "DateAssigned",
            table: "UsersProducts");
    }
```

It seems the column exists in the table, So why is this happening?

Comment: try to add it in mapping `.Property(t => t.DateAssigned).HasColumnName("DateAssigned")`

Comment: Try to change it to be DateTime in Db design.. maybe he can't map datatime(6)

Comment: Sorry seems that solved the first problem, But now I get a MySQLException when I do something like this var userProducts = context.UsersProducts.Where(x => x.User == user && x.DateAssigned.Year == DateTime.Now.Year) .GroupBy(x => x.DateAssigned.Month.ToString("MMMM")) .ToList();

Comment: What is the Exception ?

Comment: MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 125 .Query.Expressions.SqlFunctionExpression]))' at line 3

Comment: My Experience in EF with MYSQL that is still not smart to translate all queries. get your list in memory and query after that `var userProducts = context.UsersProducts.Where(x => x.User == user && x.DateAssigned == DateTime.Now) .ToList();` and after that query by year and group by

Comment: I will add my first comment as answer, if it works please verify it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add it in mapping

`.Property(t => t.DateAssigned).HasColumnName("DateAssigned")`

Comment: Thanks so much, I will probably add a stored procedure or something to finish the query

Comment: Could someone please clarify this solution? I am facing the same issue with a many to many relationship, but I haven't turned on EF Code First migrations yet (starting a migration from MVC 5 and EF6)

Comment: For others in my situation, column mapping in EF Core is explained here in the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/columns